# JDBI.inTransactionUnchecked function behaviour in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jdbi

Wanted to understand the behaviour on the JDBI.inTransactionUnchecked method.

Existing implementation attaches the DAO layers in the transaction context and then fetches the data from the DB.

Code Sample:

```java
jdbi.inTransactionUnchecked {
    val userDAO = it.attach<userDAO>() // Is it really necessary to attach userDAO to this transaction context for it to work correctly? or is there any implication of not attaching it?
    userDAO.updateUserStatus(users)
}
```

I tried checking the official documentation related to this function (https://jdbi.org/apidocs-kotlin/jdbi3-kotlin/jdbi3-kotlin/org.jdbi.v3.core.kotlin/in-transaction-unchecked.html) but I couldn't find anything.